# Creating an oracle test environment

Tags: oracle, local-storage

Am a beginner in oracle and am trying to set up an oracle environment for practice, assist me in identifying how i should go around it and what software's i should have installed to begin my journey.Links to useful sites and books will also be of help.

Comment: If you just want to learn RDBMS, I suggest you download XAMPP - then u get mysql, php and that is a good way to start - have back end and front end (phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, am well skilled in what you have mentioned in your comment; my interest for now is on how to set up an oracle environment.

Answer (score 0):

Download a complete app developement vm from [Database App Development VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html#dbapp) and dive into the documentation [Developer Essentials](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/index.htm).

That will keep you busy for a while.